# React too many re-renders when trying to implement countdown

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I would really appreciate it if you could help me. So essentially I am trying to make a countdown visible on the react app. However, I am getting the error that too many renders are occurring. I believe this is because of me updating counter inside useEffect hook itself, but I saw examples online that did this same thing (and according to them, it worked)

```
 const [question, setQuestion] = useState([]);
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(60);

  if (question === []) {
    //make API request
        setQuestion(apiResponse) //confirmed this works
  } else {
    //endingTime and currentTime are variables with the correct values (confirmed this)
    setCounter(endingTime - currentTime);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = counter > 0 && setInterval(() => setCounter(counter - 1), 1000);
    if (counter === 0) setCounter('Time is Up');
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [counter]);
```

Comment: Btw I'm really dubious that this works `question === []`. In Javascript arrays are objects, and object equality is done by reference. Ie, `[] === []; // false`

Comment: All the code in your component that is outside of a hook will run every single render. You are calling `setQuestion` or `setCounter` on every render, which causes a re-render. Simply wrap that expression in `useEffect(() => { //your stuff }, [question]);

Comment: You can also consider using a library for the counter which simplifies this for you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-useinterval for example.